# How to get my html/php form to properly insert data into my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

For a final part of my database project, we are to create working html forms by modifying the PHP files. If you check the html form link and then check my erd screenshot link, you will see "pickup/dropoff longitude/latitude" are in a different table than the rest of the values. (location & reservation)

This form, when submitted, is supposed to upload this data to the online virtual database I have created, but I don't know how I am supposed to do this since they are in different tables. Would the only way to do this in the php files be to have more than one "insert" statement?

[HTML Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFK9.png)

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vr2b.png)

Here are my create tables, if needed:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(45) NULL,
CustomerAddress VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Location (
Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Latitude VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT ' ',
Longitude VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Address));


CREATE TABLE Employee (
EmployeeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));


CREATE TABLE Truck (
LicensePlate CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR(45) NULL,
capacity VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LicensePlate));

CREATE TABLE Shifts (
ShiftTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE EmployeeShifts (
DesiredShift DATETIME NOT NULL,
EmployeeWorking INT NULL,
DateOfShift DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(DesiredShift, EmployeeWorking),
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeWorking) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (DesiredShift) REFERENCES Shifts(ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE Reservation (
ReservNum INT NOT NULL,
ReserveDate DATE NULL,
PickupTime VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
NumOfPassengers INT NULL,
sheduledTime VARCHAR(45) NULL,
ActualPickupTime VARCHAR(45),
ActualTime VARCHAR(45),
PricePaid VARCHAR(45),
DriverHourlyRate DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
PassEmployeeHourlyRate DECIMAL (7,2) NOT NULL,
DriverSalary VARCHAR(10),
PassEmployeeSalary VARCHAR(10),
Customer_CustomerID INT,
Truck_LicensePlate char(20) NOT NULL,
Employee_EmployeeID_Driver INT,
Location_Address_Pickup VARCHAR(100),
Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger INT,
Location_Address_Drop VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ReservNum),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID),
FOREIGN KEY (Truck_LicensePlate) REFERENCES Truck (LicensePlate),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Driver) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Pickup) REFERENCES Location (Address),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Drop) REFERENCES Location (Address));
```

If you mean the code for the php, here is an example of what we are given to modify. I haven't started this specific form yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>InsertNewCustomer PHP Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {text-align: center; color: blue}
        h2 {font-family: Ariel, sans-serif; text-align: left; color: blue}
        p.footer {text-align: center}
        table.output {font-family: Ariel, sans-serif}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    // Connect to the Database
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Goober", 
            'root', 'password');
        //  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,   
        //          PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'PDO Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();  
    }

    // Create short variable names
    $Driver = $_POST["Driver"];
    $DateOfShift = $_POST["DateOfShift"];
    $DesiredShift = $_POST["DesiredShift"];


    // Create SQL statement to INSERT new data
    $SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO EmployeeShifts (Driver,DateOfShift,DesiredShift)";
    $SQLINSERT .= "VALUES('$Driver','$DateOfShift', '$DesiredShift')";

    // Prepare the statement to execute
    $sqlprep = $pdo->prepare($SQLINSERT);


    // Test existence of result
    echo "<h1>
            Goober EmployeeShifts Table
        </h1>
        <hr />";
    // Test existence of result
        if ($sqlprep->execute()){

        echo "<h2>
            New Shift Added:
        </h2>
        <table>
            <tr>";
            echo "<td>Driver:</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $Driver . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>DateOfShift:</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $DateOfShift . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>DesiredShift:</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $DesiredShift . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table><br /><hr />";
        }
        else {
            exit ("SQL Statement Error: " . $SQL);
        }

    // Create SQL statement to read CUSTOMER table data
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeShifts";

// Prepare the statement to execute
$sqlprep = $pdo->prepare($SQL);
// Run statement and test existence of recordset
    if (!$sqlprep->execute())
   {
        exit ("SQL Statement Error: ");
   }


?>
    <!--  Page Headers -->
    <h1>
        The Heather Sweeney Designs CUSTOMER Table
    </h1>
    <hr />
    <h2>
        CUSTOMER
    </h2>
<?php     
    // Table headers
    echo "<table class='output' border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Driver</th>
                <th>DateOfShift</th>
                <th>DesiredShift</th>
            </tr>";

// Table data
while($RecordSetRow = $sqlprep->fetch())
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $RecordSetRow['Driver'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $RecordSetRow['DateOfShift'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $RecordSetRow['DesiredShift'] . "</td>";

        }
    echo "</table>";

?>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <p class="footer">  
        <a href="../HSD/index.html">
            Return to Home Page
        </a>
    </p>
    <hr />
</body>
```

Comment: can you put the code not just a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got this

```
$SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO EmployeeShifts (Driver,DateOfShift,DesiredShift)";
    $SQLINSERT .= "VALUES('$Driver','$DateOfShift', '$DesiredShift')";
```

but could you try

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO EmployeeShifts (Driver,DateOfShift,DesiredShift) VALUES(:Driver,:DateOfShift,:DesiredShift)";
$stmt->bindParam(':Driver', $Driver);
$stmt->bindParam(':DateOfShift', $DateOfShift);
$stmt->bindParam(':DesiredShift', $DesiredShift);

$stmt->execute();
```

or just remove the tics ' in your existing query

```
 $SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO EmployeeShifts (Driver,DateOfShift,DesiredShift)";
        $SQLINSERT .= "VALUES($Driver,$DateOfShift, $DesiredShift)";
```